# jQuery hover doesn't work

Tags: jquery, hover

I want jQuery to do something after I hover an element and do something else on mouse out.

I wrote this:

```
   jQuery('.item').hover(

        function() {
            var bg = jQuery(this).attr('data-background'); 
            jQuery(this).css("background-color", bg);
        }, 

        function() { /* this doesn't seem to work */
             alert(bg);  
        });
```

Can you tell me why this code works fine until function two, so it never alerts anything? I believe there's a typo, but I can't find it ;/

Answer (score 11):

Well, `bg` is not defined in the second function. It is only local to the first one. This will work:

```
jQuery('.item').hover(
    function() {
        var bg = jQuery(this).attr('data-background'); 
        jQuery(this).css("background-color", bg);
    }, 
    function() {
         var bg = jQuery(this).attr('data-background'); 
         alert(bg);  
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/ZETWs/)

To do justice to the upvotes, you *could* also define `bg` in a scope accessible by both functions:

```
(function() {
    var bg;
    jQuery('.item').hover(
        function() {
            bg = jQuery(this).attr('data-background'); 
            jQuery(this).css("background-color", bg);
        }, 
        function() {
            alert(bg);  
    });
 }());
```

Here the *immediate function* creates a new scope (so `bg` does not pollute the global scope). But whether this is necessary depends on what you actually want to do.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/ZETWs/1/)

---

As of jQuery 1.4.3, you can access `data-background` also with [**`.data()`**](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

```
var bg = jQuery(this).data('background');
```

Comment: @Felix Kling oh my God, is there "easy points provider" badge? Excellent! :D

Comment: Wow... 6 up votes in 1 minute? Too bad I already hit the limit ;)

Comment: @Felix Kling, you are going to get more in 7 minutes. Thanks for .data trick by the way, works like a charm. jQuery starts to look beautiful to me, at last ;)

Comment: Can you also set data useing `.data('...');` ?

Comment: @trusktr: Not on the HTML element. You would have to use `,attr('data-something',...)`. But of course you can use `data` to store data on the DOM element `.data('something',...)`. See http://api.jquery.com/data/